# Como remmplazar solo parte del valor de un atributo?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Quiero reemplazar SOLO PARTE del valor de atributos href en un documento pero no puedo encontrar bien como hacerlo, a ver si alguien me da una ayuda.
Agrego que quiero hacerlo solo con Javascript, sin Jquery u otra librería.

Quiero encontrar todos los elementos cuyo valor de su atributo href empiece con `"/pagina/"`, esto es fácil:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[href^="/pagina/"]');
```

Devuelve una lista de nodos, lo que no encuentro como hacer es como reemplazar SOLO UNA PARTE de el valor de ese atributo, quiero reemplazar:
`href="/pagina/01345"`   por   `href="/pagina_local/01345"`

Es decir solo "pagina" por "

```
pagina_local.x[0].getAttributeNode("href").value;

//Devuelve:  `/pagina/01345`
```

Tengo que lograr que devuelva:  `/pagina_local/01345`

Quizás tenga que hacerlo en varios pasos pero puede ser que haya una solución mas fácil por eso pregunto acá, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El método [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) debería hacer lo que quieres:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[href^="/pagina/"]'), function(elem) {
    elem.setAttribute('href', elem.getAttribute('href').replace('pagina', 'pagina_local'));
});
```